# How to run test automation in physical machine using usb devices

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, master-slave, jenkins-cli

I have a jenkins server which running on google cloud platform which act as my master node. And also i have a project which is running on hardware device. I want to build that project in my GCP vm and run tests (gtest , junit and etc) in physical machine(jenkins pipeline) where my device is connected. and finally i want to get that test results into my jenkins server

Answer (score 0):

You could  use an usb to ethernet dongle and assign a static IP address to the dongle for accessing the physical device via SSH. You may also need port forwarding if the device is behind a router.